# Como imprimir o resultado de uma função php de outra pagina?

Tags: php, html, lógica

Você podem me dizer como terminar esse projeto, com esse codigo abaixo eu conseguido definir a mensagem que vai aparecer a partir do numero inserido pelo usuário dado pelo administrador

```
        <form action="submit.php" method="post" >
          <nav class="zz z_meio2 borda ">
insira o código especifico ou deixe em branco para resposta padrão 
            <br>
         <input type="text" name="CODNOME"><br>
          <button type="submit" >Enviar</button>
          </nav>
        </form>
```

o código que estou usando no submit.php

```
 <?php 

//função para gerar respostas 

echo $CODNOME;

if($_POST['CODNOME'] == "001"){
  $msg = "mensagem1";
} 

else if($_POST['CODNOME'] == "002"){
  $msg = "mensagem2";
}

else {
  $msg = "opção fixa";
}

echo $msg;
?>
```

o código acima redireciona para outra pagina.

Mas gostaria que se o usuário digitar um código invalido ou não digitar nada ele imprime a "msg fixa" imprimindo ela sem mudar de pagina clicando no código abaixo.

```
<input type="submit" value="Imprimir" class="btn no-print" onClick="window.print()"> 

<div class="print" STYLE="width:660px;">

<p>msg fixa</p>

</div>
```

isso seria como se o resultado da submit.php fosse impressão do usuário, na mesma pagina, tem alguma forma de fazer isso ?

Comment: Você pode usar a `action` para a mesma página que está o formulário. Pode escrever o nome da página ou usar `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`. Depois basta verificar se a varíável post não está vazia, `if (!empty($_POST))` e coloca as condições que pretende verificar.

Comment: @lazyFox deu certo colocando na mesma pagina ele gera o  que eu queira porem agora ele não aplica a função não reconhece o valor inserido no input nem 001 nem 002 da apenas como 'else' 

como aplico o 'if (!empty($_POST))'
na 
' <input type="text" name="CODNOME"><br> '

Answer (score 1):

Coloque a pagina html junto com o arquivo php e faça isso:

```
<?php 

//função para gerar respostas 

echo $CODNOME;

if($_POST['CODNOME'] == "001"){
  $msg = "mensagem1";
} 

else if($_POST['CODNOME'] == "002"){
  $msg = "mensagem2";
}

else {
  $msg = "opção fixa";
}

echo "<input type='submit' value='Imprimir' class='btn no-print' onClick='window.print()''> 

<div class='print' STYLE='width:660px;''>

<p>$msg</p>

</div>";
?>
```

Ou você pode fazer assim também:

```
<?php 

//função para gerar respostas 

echo $CODNOME;

if($_POST['CODNOME'] == "001"){
  $_POST['msg'] = "mensagem1";
} 

else if($_POST['CODNOME'] == "002"){
  $_POST['msg'] = "mensagem2";
}

else {
  $_POST['msg'] = "opção fixa";
}

?>

<html...>
//Title, body etc
<input type='submit' value='Imprimir' class='btn no-print' onClick='window.print()''> 

<div class='print' STYLE='width:660px;''>

<p><?php echo $_POST['msg']; ?></p>

</div>
```

Comment: Colando o código na mesma pagina ele não muda a resposta sempre  mostra "opção fixa" como se a função nao estivesse sendo aplicada  somente mostrando o que tem 

**else {
  $_POST['msg'] = "opção fixa";
}**

Comment: @LuccasCerqueira essa parte eu copiei do seu código, sempre vai pra elsse porque você deve não está recebendo o $_POST['CODNOME'], como ela não existe, sempre é else